# Blackberry SQLite mass delete best practice

Tags: sqlite, blackberry

I have an SQLite database from which I need to delete records periodically.  What is the best way, performance-wise, to do this.  I have an array of unique PK ids.  I've come up with 2 methods:

Using a prepared statement

```
    int[] ids = {1,2,3,4,5}; //example only, will be built elsewhere
    Database db = null;
    try {
        db = DataConnection.getInstance(); //my class to get the connection instance
        db.beginTransaction();
        Statement st = db.createStatement("DELETE FROM myTable WHERE id = ?");
        st.prepare();
        for (int i=0;i<ids.length;i++) {
            st.bind(1, ids[i]);
            st.execute();
            st.reset();
        }
        db.commitTransaction();
    } catch (FileIOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (DatabaseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Or by using the 'in' keyword

```
    int[] ids = {1,2,3,4,5}; //example only, will be built elsewhere
    Database db = null;
    try {
        db = DataConnection.getInstance();
        //Util.JoinArray(int[] ids,char delim, char prepend, char postpend) returns a String of the ids separated by delim with prepend at the front and postpend at the end
        Statement st = db.createStatement("DELETE FROM myTable WHERE id IN " + Util.joinArray(ids,',','(',')'));
        st.prepare();
    } catch (FileIOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (DatabaseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ideal approach would be a combination of the two: a prepared statement of all IDs.

So, avoid SQL injection and use an approach like this (in pseudo-code):

```
query = "DELETE FROM myTable WHERE id IN (";
for (int i = 0; i < ids.count; i++)
    query.Append("?,");
query.DropLast(); //Remove the last comma
query.Append(")");
st = db.createStatement(query);
st.prepare();
for (int i = 0; i < ids.count; i++)
    st.bind(i+1, ids[i]);
```

Performance-wise, this *might* be better as the database will rebalance indexes after all deletes. Working in a transaction and committing once after all individual deletes would do essentially the same, though. The approach I propose is only safer.

As often discussed on SO, SQLite performance varies greatly on various criteria, namely the structure, number of rows, page size, etc. There is no universal "faster in all cases" approach with SQLite. Your mileage will vary.

Comment: I've used that approach before with MySQL and servlets.  It just seemed like extra work to build the (?,?...) and bind rather than just build the id in that String.  It's from an int[] so I didn't think SQL injection an issue. If I had a String PK, I'd do it that way.

Comment: @kyle To be honest, ever since I hacked together in a rush (with shame) something I call the "SQL injection engine", I'm a bit paranoid, but yes, I guess it's superflous to do it with ints.

Comment: +1. But SQLite IN clause takes a max of 999 arguments. http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html

Comment: @MisterSmith in those ranges, either use a subquery or loop through batches of 999. But really look into using that subquery!